# Detect Websocket source closure with akka-stream and Java

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm playing with Akka stream and connect to a Websocket service that close the connection after receiving a message.

I would like to be able to detect the close, so that I can reconnect to the service. So I have an `Source.fromCompletionStage(response)` where I can send message to the server by completing the response (`CompletionStage`) but I'm unable to catch the closing.

Comment: could you please add more details about your code, your config and what you tried?

Comment: I would like to add them. But what kind of details do you expect ? I just want to be able to detect when a Source is closed so that I can reopen it.